# Priorizar palavra em consulta SQL - MsSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho a seguinte tarefa:

Fazer uma consulta onde tenho que dar preferência à palavra passada como parâmetro.

Eu pesquiso em dois campos com um `OR`, mas eu preciso priorizar a consulta pelo primeiro campo.

Por exemplo: se pesquiso por "%fisica%", atualmente traz a palavra fisica nos dois campos, porem o mais importante é o primeiro campo, pois como estou fazendo um `OR`, na primeira coluna que exibo o resultado aparece fisica no começo e vem um monte de outros resultados, e depois mais "fisica", "educação fisica".

Não sei se expliquei direito, mas espero que alguém tenha uma ideia para resolver isso, já procurei como louco.

Comment: Não entendi. Não seria simplesmente pesquisar usando `WHERE campo = 'fisica'`?

Comment: Tem parte do seu SQL? Edita pra gente analisar, coloque exemplos.

Comment: o seu banco de dados é o `mysql`ou o `sql server`?

Comment: Você que realizar uma pesquisa exata e, caso não encontre nada, uma pesquisa aproximada. É isso? Não veja uma forma de se fazer isso em apenas uma etapa.

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck se for isso ele poderia trabalhar com um `UNION`.

Comment: @rodrigorigotti poderia, mas até agora eu não entendi bem o que ele quer. Se for apenas por questão de ordenação ele pode fazer um **pesquisa exata** union **pesquisa aproximada - pesquisa exata**

Comment: Lembre-se de escolher a melhor resposta. Você faz diversas perguntas e quem responde gosta de ter um feedback também. Abraço.

Answer (score 2):

Creio que a solução com `UNION` ou `UNION ALL` seria um tanto ruim para o desempenho, já que duas *queries* seriam executadas.

A solução do @ademario é boa, mas a *query* pode ser mais simples, isto é, não há necessidade de *subquery*.

Além disso, uma outra funcionalidade interessante em sistemas de busca é priorizar não somente um campo em relação ao outro, mas também quando os dois campos possuem a palavra.

Veja esta *query*:

```sql
select tabela.*,
       (
         case when campo1 like '%fisica%' then 2 else 0 end +
         case when campo2 like '%fisica%' then 1 else 0 end
       ) as peso
  from tabela
 where campo1 like '%fisica%'
    or campo2 like '%fisica%'
order by peso desc
```

A coluna `peso` irá retornar:

- `3` quando a palavra estiver nos dois campos
- `2` quando a mesma estiver apenas no campo1 (prioritário)
- `1` quanto ela estiver apenas no campo2 (menos importante)

#### Exemplo funcional no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b715/4)

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que seria uma consulta assim (é bom sempre mostrar um exemplo para todos entenderem):

```
SELECT CAMPO1, CAMPO2
FROM TABELA
WHERE CAMPO1 LIKE '%FISICA%' OR CAMPO2 LIKE '%FISICA%';
```

e que sua intenção é exibir primeiro os que atendem a condição do campo1 antes do campo2.
 Você pode classificar seus resultados  usando uma coluna com condição no select e ordenar por ela. veja:

```
Select * from (
   SELECT CASE WHEN CAMPO1 LIKE '%FISICA%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS ORDEM, CAMPO1, CAMPO2
   FROM TABELA
   WHERE CAMPO1 LIKE '%FISICA%' OR CAMPO2 LIKE '%FISICA%'
)
ORDER BY ORDEM;
```

Isso vale para qualquer organização que foge de uma ordenação simples, ajuda até a alterar a forma de exibir informação no select de acordo com suas necessidades.

Comment: `ORDER BY ORDEM`, não?

Comment: Opa, mania do oracle. foi mal :)

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi e se seria a melhor maneira, mas você poderia fazer algo assim. 
Exemplificarei as diversas formas que eu entendi.

Acho que o que você quis dizer foi isso, uma consulta que filtre os resultados por uma certa palavra chave em dois campos. Todos os resultados que tiverem localizado a palavra no campo prioritário, deve vir primeiro.

```
SELECT campoA, campoB, campoC, 
 CASE WHEN minhacoluna1 LIKE '%fisica%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS prioridade
 FROM minhatabela WHERE minhacoluna1 LIKE '%fisica%' OR minhacoluna2 LIKE '%fisica%'
 ORDER BY prioridade ASC
```

Para consultar exatamente uma coluna coluna e outra aproximada, e ordenando pelos resultados exatos:

```
(SELECT campoA, campoB, campoC, 1 AS prioridade 
 FROM minhatabela WHERE minhacoluna1 LIKE 'fisica')
 UNION
(SELECT campoA, campoB, campoC, 2 AS prioridade 
 FROM minhatabela WHERE minhacoluna2 LIKE '%fisica%')
ORDER BY prioridade ASC
```

Para priorizar resultados de uma mesma coluna iniciada a palavra buscada na primeira posição (início do texto) dos demais resultados com a palavra buscada em outras posições:.

```
SELECT * FROM minhatabela 
         WHERE minhacoluna LIKE 'fisica%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM minhatabela 
         WHERE minhacoluna LIKE '%fisica%' 
         AND minhacoluna NOT LIKE 'fisica%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi da sua descrição, você poderia utilizar o seguinte select:

```
SELECT campos, 1 AS flag_busca FROM tabela where campo LIKE '%fisica%'
UNION
SELECT campos, 2 AS flag_busca from tabela where outro_campo LIKE '%fisica%'
```

As linhas dos campos que você quer "priorizar" virão com flag_busca = 1, os outros com flag_busca = 2.

Lembrando que para utilizar o `UNION` você deve ter o mesmo número de colunas nos dois selects.